# Swift draw infinite sine curve (UIBezierpath)

Tags: swift, user-interface, graph

```
class GraphView: UIView {

private let axesDrawer = AxesDrawer()
private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
private var axesCenter: CGPoint? { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
private var positionX: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .Changed, .Ended:
        scale *= recognizer.scale
        recognizer.scale = 1.0
    default: break
    }
}

func moveAxes(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    case .Changed:
        if axesCenter == nil {
            axesCenter = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        }
        let changePoint = recognizer.translationInView(self)
        axesCenter = CGPoint(x: axesCenter!.x + changePoint.x, y: axesCenter!.y + changePoint.y)
        positionX += changePoint.x
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), inView: self)
    default:
        break
    }
}

func drawGraph() -> UIBezierPath {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let positionY = (axesCenter == nil) ? frame.height / 2 : (axesCenter?.y)! // find the vertical center

    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX, y: positionY))

    for i in Int(frame.minX)...Int(frame.maxX) {
        let x = CGFloat(i) + positionX
        let y = (sin(Double(i) * 0.1) * Double(axesDrawer.minimumPointsPerHashmark) * Double(scale)) + Double(positionY)
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: x, y: CGFloat(y)))
    }

    path.lineWidth = 1
    return path
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    axesDrawer.contentScaleFactor = self.contentScaleFactor
    axesDrawer.drawAxesInRect(self.bounds, origin: axesCenter ?? CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY), pointsPerUnit: CGFloat(50) * scale)
    UIColor.redColor().set()
    drawGraph().stroke()
}
}
```

Moving towards:

[left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayxLn.png)

[right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dogiG.png)

I'm trying to draw "infinite" sine curve. The problem is that it doesn't redraw itself when I try to move around the view.

If you look at the links I provided, on the `left` side an infinite line appears, and If you go `right` the curve just stops.

How can I update UI for the curve to be redrawn every time I try to move around the view?

Comment: Maybe this works(not tested) Make a function that gets called when the user swipes, and then calls `drawGraph().stroke()`. But I guess it will then not remove the last one

Comment: @Eric, `drawGraph().stroke()` is getting called inside `drawRect` function, every time `axesCenter`, `positionX` or `scale` gets set.